# How to rotate u and v components of wind in rotated gribs?

Tags: python, data, grib

I have a [grib](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRIB) message of a rotated hirlam product.

The grib message states, that the u and v component contained are relative to the rotated grid.

How can I unrotate them?

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to provide more details of what you do to see the message, and also what the precise error message you see is, please?